# What is the correct antenna configuration for an Intel Centrino 6300 module on a Dell Studio XPS 16?

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-xps, dell-studio, intel-centrino

I purchased an upgraded wireless card (Intel Centrino 6300) for my Dell Studio XPS 16, and need to know the correct antenna configuration. There were no install instructions for the wireless card, nor does the laptop itself explain the antenna configurations.

The laptop has three antenna cables, black, white, and grey. One of them was not used on the old wireless module. The wireless seems to work with the assignment I've chosen, but I've been having some connectivity issues which are perhaps related to an improper configuration.

Answer (score 9):

I have purchased the same card and after quite some research I did it this way:

1. white cable (main connector)
2. black cable (aux connector)
3. grey cable (middle connector for MIMO)

Performance is great!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably way too late for the Original Poster, but you can find the dell branded versions of the Intel card on Ebay. The white and black wires stay exactly like they were, and the gray wire is in the middle. So position 1 is white, position 2 is black, and position 3 is gray. If you have the card turned so that the mini PCI-E connector is on the bottom and the wireless hookups are on top, position 1 is on the left (white), position 2 is on the right (black), and position 3 is in the middle (gray).

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the Dell site

.
[image]

[Source Page](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/sxl16/en/sm/minicard.htm#wp1181828)

.

I could find nothing on the Intel site about that particular card and the antenna connections

Comment: Yeah I have that info too, sadly it's of absolutely no help.

Comment: I think you need to connect all 3 antenna wires.

Comment: Well, obviously. And they are all hooked up -- but I don't know which color goes to which number.

Comment: There was no information that came with the card when you bought it? If not contact Intel Support and ask.

Comment: Intel doesn't do consumer facing support for oem parts, and the oem parts don't come with manuals, unfortunately.

Comment: @Charles Randall, I have gotten superb support from Intel on a few OEM problems of mine, not sure what your experience with Intel has been.

Answer (score 2):

For other late comers, the answer is so obvious, many have missed it.  The card has color coded triangles on it next to the connectors.[image]
[image]

Comment: not all of them got colors - https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51lgf9GPuSL._AC_SY400_.jpg
which is a bit weird then, because on a Lenovo laptop the wires were Gray, White, Black (not sure if they have been moved by someone tho)

Comment: That’s an Intel WiFi Link, not Centrino. The question was specifically for the Centrino 6300 in a Dell XPS, that image is a WiFi Link 5300, different model.